# Can we use "return" in finally block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally, finally

Can we use  return statement in **finally** block. Can this cause any problem?

Comment: You might also go through [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18131447/1679863)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Returning from inside a `finally` block will cause `exceptions` to be lost.

**A return statement inside a finally block will cause any exception that might be thrown in the try or catch block to be discarded.**

According to the [**Java Language Specification:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)

> If execution of the try block completes abruptly for any other reason
>   R, then the finally block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
> ```
>    If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement
>    completes  abruptly for reason R.
>
>    If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try
>    statement  completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is
>    discarded).
> ```

*Note: As per [JLS 14.17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) - a return statement always completes abruptly.*

Comment: the JLS quote does not support your claim about return statement inside finally block?

Comment: These lines from JLS are for exceptions but these are also true for return statement.

Comment: I still don't get the relation between the quote and your statement- so I wrote [a piece of code](http://ideone.com/1GaeBo) which shows that, when the finally block contains return statement, exceptions thrown from catch block get eaten, but the ones thrown from try block get caught. Please verify.

Comment: Go through this code http://ideone.com/AU9KvS

. Your Exception from try is eaten.

Comment: I completely missed the variant without the catch block! Thank you, upvoted already :)

Comment: The Java Language Specification is clear about the return: The return statement always completes abruptly. (reference: http://thegreyblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/do-not-return-in-finally-block-return.html)

Comment: You should add to your answer that `return` is considered as abrupt completion by Java spec.

Comment: @kolobok Added the note.

Answer (score 47):

Yes you can write the return statement in a finally block and it will override the other return value.

EDIT:
For example in below code

```
public class Test {

    public static int test(int i) {
        try {
            if (i == 0)
                throw new Exception();
            return 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 1;
        } finally {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(test(0));
        System.out.println(test(1));
    }
}
```

The output is always 2, as we are returning 2 from the finally block. Remember the finally always executes whether there is a exception or not. So when the finally block runs it will override the return value of others. Writing return statements in finally block is not required, in fact you should not write it.

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: try{ throws new exception(); } catch{ throws new exception();} finally{ return 5; }  Here What happends???

Comment: @Rakesh It returns `5`

Comment: It may not work fine if a System.exit(0) call is done from try or the catch block. The control will not go to finally block in that case.

Comment: System.exit(0) prevent the execution of finally block as the JVM is going to shut down, no matter what return

Comment: @RakeshKR it will return 5, because exception that thrown by catch block it will handled by finally block, and if you remove finally block so in given case it will give compile time error, so either you add finally block or explicitly you will need to handle it.

Comment: This is crazy. I was wondering for years why in Listing 7.12 "Encapsulating nonstandard cancellation in task with newTaskFor" in the Java Concurrency in Practice he would `return super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);` specifically in finally block. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can,But  you should not 1 ,because  [the finally block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) is meant for a special purpose.

> finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

Writing your logic inside it is not recommended.

Comment: This does not really explain much. TJ Crowder's answer here is much better - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225819/try-catch-finally-return-clarification

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev If it is too detailed ..please go and read about it. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can write `return` statement in `finally` block but the value returned from `try` block will be updated on the stack and not the `finally` block return value.

Let us say you have this function

```
private Integer getnumber(){
Integer i = null;
try{
   i = new Integer(5);
   return i;
}catch(Exception e){return 0;}
finally{
  i = new Integer(7);
  System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

and you are calling this from main method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.println(getNumber());
}
```

This prints

```
7
5
```

Comment: The question is about if we can return a value from finally block or not. Remember return statement in finally will override the other return values.

Consider the below code snippet:
   class ReturnClass {        public int testValue() {           try {               return 3;           }           catch(Exception e) {           }           finally {                return 5;           }       }        public static void main(String ar[]) {           ReturnClass rc = new ReturnClass();           System.out.println(rc.testValue());} }
Output will be always 5.

Comment: This is off topic. It got me confused until I carefully read that you are not `return`ing the control from `finally`, rather just printing something from there.