# Code working fine even after StackOverflow - How?

Tags: java, error-handling, stack-overflow

To my understanding following code should print `0` as output because stack is full and it should get out of method immediately.

However when I ran the following code it is printing `100` for first case and prints `1` for second case:

```
class ErrorAndException {
        public static int callStackOverflow() {
            try {
                callStackOverflow();
                return 100;
            } catch (Error e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                return 0;
            } finally {
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(callStackOverflow());
        }
    }
```

Case - 2

```
class ErrorAndException {
            public static int callStackOverflow() {
                try {
                    callStackOverflow();
                    return 100;
                } catch (Error e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    return 0;
                } finally {
                           return 1
                }
            }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(callStackOverflow());
        }
    }
```

Please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: Case 2: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18205493/3788176

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the final call to `callStackOverflow()` (the one in which `StackOverflowError` is thrown) returns `0`. But when it returns, the previous calls to `callStackOverflow()` all return 100. Your `main` method prints just the value returned by the initial call to `callStackOverflow()`, which is `100`.

If you want the `0` to be returned to the `main` method, `callStackOverflow()` would have to return the value returned by the recursive call:

```
public static int callStackOverflow() {
    try {
        return callStackOverflow();
    } catch (Error e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    } finally {
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean on stack overflow error , JVM will perform complete stack unwind until it reaches to first call, I was thinking program will terminate from last call only

Comment: @ShowStopper why would you think that? The stack still contains all the previous calls to `callStackOverflow()`, so they must be unwound before the `main` method is reached.

Comment: thanks a lot, one more thing I have edited my question it is printing 1 if I put return statement in finally, please help me understand this as well, in this case stack unwinding is not performed ?

Comment: @ShowStopper `finally` is executed regardless if an exception was thrown by the try clause or not, and regardless of whether such as exception was caught by the catch clause. Therefore if you put a `return 1;` statement in the finally clause, 1 will always be returned. Unwinding is still performed, but all the recursive calls of your method return 1.

Comment: It seems to be a common expectation that a return executed from a recursive call that's 'N' levels deep will someone magically effect a return from the very first entry into the function.

Answer (score 4):

The final item that causes the overflow will return 0 to the previous instance, but that value is lost as all lower instances just return 100 to one another until the final instance exits returning 100.