# Java exception thrown in a "try" block cannot get caught outside of the "try...catch"

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am using my own personalized java exception DaoException (inherited from java.lang.Exception) that I throw inside of a try block inside of a method. The problem is that though I only catch other types of exceptions (such as java.sql.SQLException), it seems that the DaoException cannot get outside of the block as well. When I use my method elsewhere, I cannot catch my DaoException, as if it never was thrown.

I have no compilation or execution errors, so I am quite confused, especially because when throwing my DaoException outside of the try block, it works normally.

I could not find anyone who had the same problem, so I really hope to find some help here.

Here is the structure of my method:

```
public Member getById(int id) throws DaoException
{
    ...
    try
    {
        ...
        if (id<0){
           throw new DaoException("Indice de membre invalide");}
        ...
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        throw new DaoException("[SQLException]"+e.getLocalizedMessage());   
    }
    finally
    {
        return member;
    }
}
```

And here is my DaoException, which is quite basical:

```
public class DaoException extends Exception
{
    public DaoException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18205628/477878

Comment: everything you need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2

Comment: You will get a warning with this. Make sure you've turned on warnings and take note of them.

Answer (score 4):

You have a return in your `finally` block. That means you're throwing away the exception when it happens so that you can return instead.

If you want the exception to survive, don't return in the `finally` block.

Comment: Thank you, you're right it works if I move the `return` outside of the `finally` block! I didn't know that the return statement is prioritary to the throwing, but it's actually quite logical :)