# Modifying a return value of a method in a finally block doesn't return the actual modified value

Tags: java

As a rule, the `finally` block is always executed whether or not an exception is thrown in the `try` block or a `continue`, `break` or `return` statement encounters in the `try` block itself.

Accordingly, the return value of the method in the code snippet given below should be changed but it doesn't.

```
final class Product
{
    private String productName=null;

    public Product(String productName)
    {
        this.productName=productName;
    }

    public String getProductName()
    {
        try
        {
            return this.productName;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.productName="The product name has been modified in the finally block.";
            System.out.println("Product name in the finally block : "+this.productName);
        }
    }
}

public final class Test
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        System.out.println(new Product("Intel core i3").getProductName());
    }
}
```

The method `getProductName()` simply returns the product name which is assigned by the constructor to the field `productName` before this method is invoked.

Before this method returns, the value of `productName` is modified in the `finally` block. Therefore, the method should return this new modified value but it returns the initial value which is assigned to `productName` when an instance of this class has been constructed.

---

It produces the following output:

> Product name in the finally block : The product name has been modified in the finally block.
>   Intel core i3

Why doesn't this method return the new value which is assigned to the `productName` field in the `finally` block? It should return the new value. Shouldn't it?

Comment: I regularly visit your profile and see that you ask good questions. Understanding this much stuff at this stage in Java (including advanced Java frameworks and enterprise Java) is not so easy. Keep up good work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is that you are returning a reference value to the respective object from your method. And in the caller side, what you get is the copy of the reference of the method. Remember, everything in Java are passed by value. Even the references are passed by value.

When you modify the object using the reference in the `finally` block, the changes will be visible on the caller side. But, if you change the value of the `reference` itself, then the changes would of course not be reflected on the caller side, as now both of them have a different references.

> Before this method returns, the value of productName is modified in the finally block.

What you have done in the `finally` block is, you've assigned a new `String` object to the `productName` reference. That will change the the reference value of `productName`. And thus as per the above paragraph, the changes wouldn't be reflected on the caller end. Both of them are dealing with 2 different String objects.

> Therefore, the method should return this new modified value.

No, it shouldn't. Because both the String objects are different alltogether. Try this code with a `StringBuilder` object:

```
public StringBuilder getProductName() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(productName);
    try {
        return sb;
    }
    finally {
        sb.append("Modified");
    }
}
```

Now the changes to the `StringBuilder` will be reflected in the return value. So what is happening here?

First with the following return statement:

```
return sb;
```

you returned a reference to the `StringBuilder` object you created. Then in the `finally` block:

```
sb.append("Modified");
```

.. you've modified the object pointed to by `sb`. Since you haven't changed the reference value of `sb` itself, the changes to the object will be visible for all the references pointing to that object, and hence the one at the caller end too.

Now modify the `finally` block as:

```
sb = new StringBuilder("Modified");
```

and see whether the change is reflected or not. You will not see any change in return value. Because, now you have changed the reference value of `sb` itself.

Further, if you return the modified reference from the `finally` block, the original returned value would be overwritten. Try modifying your `finally` block to:

```
finally {

    this.productName="The product name has been modified in the finally block.";
    System.out.println("Product name in the finally block : "+this.productName);

    return this.productName;  // Note: This is bad idea
}
```

Now you will see the new value.

---

**See also:**

- [java: try finally blocks execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18131447/1679863)

Comment: This `StringBuilder` example is nice to understand. Thanks.

Comment: The first code snippet demonstrates that changes to `StringBuilder` are reflected in the return value but assigning `null` to `sb` (`sb = null`) in the `finally` block, for example has no effect anymore (which is not reflected in the return value). Could you please comment something on it. (I understand that it is already covered in the answer and after about four months, it may not be reasonable to ask this but sometimes, when I think about it, I just skip/avoid this thing, when I don't understand it literally after thinking hard).

Comment: @Tiny Assume that you've two references `stackSB` and `localSB` to the same `StringBuilder` object. Now, when you do `localSB.append("abc")`,  you'll see the change for `stackSB` right? But when you do `localSB = null`, will that also make `stackSB` equals to `null`? Think about it.

Comment: The answer is *no* and this should be a conclusion. Am I right? Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Tiny Yes, you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the finally block is not doing a `return this.productName`.

The return `this.productName` in the try block returns the address of the object.  The assignment in the finally block creates a new object, leaving the return value unchanged.