# Adding return in finally hides the exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I have the following code

```
public static void nocatch()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Which gives the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unhandled exception type CustomException
```

Which is as expected, but adding a `return` statement in the `finally` block makes the error go away

```
public static void nocatch()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    finally
    {
        return; //makes the error go away! 
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain me what is going on? and why the error disappears?

Note : I wrote this code purely for experimental purposes!

Comment: Related post: [try finally blocks execution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18131447/1679863). Although that doesn't talk about the exception, but the reasoning for this is same as that.

Comment: Side-note: don't try running code that doesn't compile. There's really no benefit in doing so. Talk about the compile-time error, rather than the exception you get from running code that hasn't compiled to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just wanted to point out the error that it caused, which is why I ran the code.

Comment: @codeMan: But you didn't need to run the code - you just needed to note the compiler error. What benefit was there in running the code? It just obscured the compiler error message by adding cruft around it.

Comment: @jonskeet you are right compiler error should have been good enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error disappears because your code is now valid. (Not nice, but valid.)

If a `finally` block just has a straight `return;` statement, then the overall try/catch/finally or try/finally statement can't throw any exceptions - so you don't need to declare that it *can* throw an exception.

In your original code, your `try` block could (well, it *will*) throw `Exception` (or `CustomException` in your real code, apparently) - and that's a checked exception, which means you have to either catch it or declare that the method might throw it.

Comment: I wonder if the exception-killing behavior of returns in Java's `finally` blocks was a deliberately-provided feature, or if Gosling et al. simply didn't think it was worth the effort to prevent?  I would hope it was the former, though if that was the case it would have been good for Gosling et al. to have documented an "unenforced requirement" that a `finally` block may only *legitimately* return in cases where the code knows that no exception could be pending (e.g. because a flag was set as the very last operation in a `try` or `catch` block).

Answer (score 0):

As per the javadoc...

```
The finally block always executes when the try block exits. 
This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs.
```

So your code is doing it correctly now.

Comment: Can you add a link?

Comment: @DataDino https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html