# what happens to the exception thrown in try block if an expectation is thrown again in finally block?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to understand what happens to the exception thrown in try block, when an exception occurs again in finally block?

After running code below, I only see exception thrown in finally block. I am trying to understand what happens to the exception in thrown in try block?

```
        try{
            int i = 10/0;
        }
        finally {
                System.out.println("one");

                int[] a = new int[2];
                a[4] = 0;

                System.out.println("two");
        }
```

Comment: finally shouldn't have any exception-prone code. It needs to *finalize* the code block, if anything goes wrong. I.E. closing files, connections and so on. The error will be thrown inside the `finally` if it has one.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861617/adding-return-in-finally-hides-the-exception

Comment: Also, you don't see exception in the try block, but it happens nevertheless. It is simply not shown to you, because you were supposed to handle the exception yourself in `finally`

Answer (score 1):

The exception in the `try` block gets discarded and forgotten, as specified in the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2):

> - If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly because of a `throw` of a value V, then there is a choice:
>
> ....
>
> > - If the run-time type of V is not assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any `catch` clause of the `try` statement, then the `finally` block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
> > > - If the `finally` block completes normally, then the `try` statement completes abruptly because of a `throw` of the value V.
>
> > > - **If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason S, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason S (and the `throw` of value V is discarded and forgotten).**